# List all parent directoriy hierarchy

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh

How to get the list of all parent directories.

Suppose I am currently in

```
% pwd
/media/blueray/WDPurple/_DataBackup/_Work/_NotesFilteredADOC/linux/shell-command-language/zsh-scripting
```

I want

```
0 /media/blueray/WDPurple/_DataBackup/_Work/_NotesFilteredADOC/linux/shell-command-language/zsh-scripting
1 /media/blueray/WDPurple/_DataBackup/_Work/_NotesFilteredADOC/linux/shell-command-language
2 /media/blueray/WDPurple/_DataBackup/_Work/_NotesFilteredADOC/linux/
3 /media/blueray/WDPurple/_DataBackup/_Work/_NotesFilteredADOC/
4 /media/blueray/WDPurple/_DataBackup/_Work/
5 /media/blueray/WDPurple/_DataBackup/
6 /media/blueray/WDPurple/
7 /media/blueray/
8 /media/
9 /
```

I actually need to pipe this output to `rofi -dmenu` so that I can easily cd into the parent directories.

Current solution that I am using with `pushd` is

```
function d () {
  select=$( dirs -v | head -10 | rofi -dmenu ) 
  cd -${select:0:1}
}
```

Comment: Mainly zsh. Bash will also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop, starting at `$PWD` and stripping off one directory level at a time. You just need to be careful about ending at `/`. Also count the lines (or pipe through `nl`). Here's a function that works both in bash and in zsh.

```
function pwd_and_parents {
  local d n
  d=$PWD
  n=0
  while [[ $d = *[!/]* ]]; do
    printf '%d %s\n' "$n" "$d"
    d=${d%/*}
    ((++n))
  done
  echo "$n /"
}
```

My version doesn't put trailing slashes. Add them if you want.

Comment: If I try `d="$(dirname $d)"` instead of `d=${d%/*}`, it does not work. Can you please explain why?

Comment: @blueray That works unless the directory path contains a whitespace or wildcard character. It should be `d="$(dirname "$d")"`.